# Config.cmake file for custom made shared libraries

Tags: cmake

I have [this](https://bitbucket.org/apalomer/qtpluginexample) project that I have done for experimentation with Qt and shared libraries. This is basically a couple of Qt Widgets from the tutorials for Qt and what I think is the right CMakeLists configuration so a `MylibConfig.cmake` is automatically generated from a `MylibConfig.cmake.in` to share the library. The problem is that I don't want the end user to add the dependencies of my library to its own `CMakeLists.txt`. This is, in my case, the library depends on Qt4, but I want that the end user to not have to do `find_package(Qt 4 REQUIRED)`. Imagine that I want to provide an enclosed functionality to someone that does not need or want to know about what my library is built on. Is there a way in the automatic generation of the `MylibConfig.cmake` that it automatically finds all necessary packages or is the only option to add the fin package manually in the `MylibConfig.cmake.in`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure there is. What have you tried? Have you had a look into other projects?

Comment: I've looked into [PCL](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl) as well as [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) but have not understood how they do it.

Comment: @apalomer, I would say that the question topic quite confusing... "custom made" sounds like libs are made w/o CMake. Better name, I believe, could like "How to include transitive dependencies/packages into `*Config.cmake` module" ... or similar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, both mentioned projects do find of dependencies from their `*Config.cmake` files. And nowadays that is the only option -- CMake can't help you to do it "automatically".

So, some way or another, your config module should do the same.
The easy way is to add [`find_dependency()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html) calls (cuz you know exactly what other packages, your project is based on).
A little bit harder is to do it "automatically" (writing your own helper function) -- for example by inspecting properties of your target(s), "searching" where all that libraries come from and finally generating `find_dependency()` calls anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using cmake 2.8 still so I guess I can not use [`find_dependency()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html) since I believe it was introduced in cmake 3.0

Comment: @apalomer, as the docs said, it just a wrapper around "native" `find_package` to pass some named args from "outer" finder module to the depended one ("inner")... You can use `find_package` instead... and pass (or not pass) named params of your module.

Comment: ... and that is always a good idea to use as latest as possible CMake :)